# How do I set an environment variable for Ansible itself not using shell?

Tags: ansible, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I would like to keep tmp directory on the VM in my test region. There is the following solution for the problem: setting ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES to 1 on the Ansible machine.

The issue is that the ansible machine is a local docker container so I need to ensure that this variable is always set. Otherwise I'm loosing some documents. When I reboot my system and start this docker container with Ansible I'm loosing this variable.

Is there a way to set this environment variable somewhere in Ansible configuration = or in a playbook configuration somewhere? I need a permanent solution in order not to forget this variable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"Is there a way to set this environment variable somewhere in Ansible configuration?"*

A: Yes. It is. For example

```
$ cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
keep_remote_files = true
```

See [DEFAULT_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-keep-remote-files).

Comment: @Hi Vladimir, could you please help a little bit more? is there a way to keep all the /tmp directory while having remote_tmp = /tmp/ansible/ ?

Comment: I don't understand. What exactly is "all the /tmp directory"?

Comment: just a /tmp directory on the VM ansible manages. I've got my app running on this VM and it has some data stored in /tmp for now

Comment: (Ansible off-topic). This depends on the OS and/or VM, I think, e.g. [How is the /tmp directory cleaned up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up). Open new question, please.

Comment: yes, I know about the specifics of the tmp directory, this is a temporal solution. We're not given a NAS yet. anyway, thanks, I'll open a new question about!